# Minecraft 1.17.1 Forge Snapshot Obfuscation Mappings

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am a beginner in modding Minecraft and would like to modify the latest release of the **Forge** version of **Minecraft (v1.17.1)**. I know how to setup a gradle project for **1.16.5**, and can for the most part do it for 1.17.1. The problem is that I have no idea what **obfuscation mappings** are for Forge 1.17.1. I need to know so that I have the correct mappings to put for **line 34** of **build.gradle**:

```java
34 | mappings channel: 'snapshot', version: '{snapshot-version}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1.17.1, Forge uses the official mappings from Mojang. Change the following:

```
   mappings channel: 'official', version: '1.17.1'
```